# Custom sorting order - DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

Is it possible to sort this in a datagridview without padding the data to 3 values after the +.
The datatype is string and the datagridview column is text.

```
10:10+01
10:10+100
10:10+110
10:10+10
```

Should sort like this

```
 10:10+01
 10:10+10
 10:10+100
 10:10+110
```

Maybe changing the sortingmode to programmatic might help?

Any input would be appreciated

Edit: Example of the data being copied to dt and then bound with a dataview.

```
DataTable dtTest = new DataTable();
dtTest.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
dtTest.Rows.Add("10:11+1");
dtTest.Rows.Add("10:11+101");
dtTest.Rows.Add("10:11+101");
dtTest.Rows.Add("10:11+2");
dtTest.Rows.Add("10:11+200");
dtTest.Rows.Add("10:10+1110");
DataView dvTest = new DataView(dtTest);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dvTest;
```

Example sort ordering

```
10:10+1110
10:11+1
10:11+101
10:11+101
10:11+2
10:11+200
```

Comment: either create a column with the data modified to work with the normal sort or, yes, change to programmatic. sounds harder than it is..just 1-3 function, as far as I remember..

Comment: Your data have changed but the solution below will work, after expanding the padding a little..However you didn't mention before  that the DGV is DataBound!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Custom sorting an unbound DataGridview

Not sure about your data, but taking them literally this will do the job for an **unbound** `DataGridView DGV`:

First you need to hook up a `SortCompare` handler, maybe like this

```
 DGV.SortCompare += new DataGridViewSortCompareEventHandler(  this.DGV_SortCompare);
```

If necessary you can call it on your column (or let the Header click do the job):

```
 DGV.Sort(DGV.Columns[yourColumn], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

This is the SortCompare event code. It uses simple string manipulation to create a sortable version by padding the last part with zeroes.

```
 private void DGV_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
 {
   string s1 = e.CellValue1.ToString().Substring(0, 6) + 
               e.CellValue1.ToString().Substring(6).PadLeft(5, '0');
   string s2 = e.CellValue2.ToString().Substring(0, 6) + 
               e.CellValue2.ToString().Substring(6).PadLeft(5, '0');
   e.SortResult = s1.CompareTo(s2);
   e.Handled = true;
 }
```

There is a comprehensive discussion of three methods to sort a DGV [here on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms171608%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - Clearly this is the easiest one for your problem. Also rather flexible: You can use the `e.columnIndex` parameter to create spearate comparison strings for other columns as well..

If other columns need no special sorting code you should insert this line to the beginning of the `SortCompare`:

```
  if (e.Column.Index != yourColumn) return;
```

### Custom sorting a data bound DataGridView

**Update:** Since you have changed your question to a **DataBound DGV**, here is a similar solution for this case:

```
BindingSource BS = new BindingSource();

private void sortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DT.Columns.Add("TempSort");
    foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
    {
        string val = row[yourcolumn].ToString();
        row["TempSort"] = val.ToString().Substring(0, 6) + 
                          val.ToString().Substring(6).PadLeft(5, '0');
    }
    BS.DataSource = DT;
    BS.Sort = "TempSort ASC";
    DT.Columns.Remove("TempSort");
    DGV.DataSource = BS;
}
```

This solution assumes your `DataSource` is a `DataTable DT` and will create a temporary column called "TempSort"`and fills it with the prepared version of the data values; it will sort ascending.

For the sorting we use a `BindingSource`.

To control the right column (here called '`yourcolumn`') dynamically as well as the sort order, you will have to write some code yourself, responding to the `ColumnHeaderClick`...

Comment: Thanks for you input TaW and example.  I've edited my post with example data.  I've added the SortCompare event but it doesn't seem to fire when I click the column header.  I've added event and forced a sort using "dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);" but its still not firing DGV_SortCompare